# Laravel oauth faild login logged in laravel.log

Tags: php, laravel

When the failed login in my site, logged error in laravel.log file. I use laravel passport for the api authentication.

Error:

```
[2018-08-06 13:27:35] local.ERROR: League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException: The user credentials were incorrect. in /home/roberto/new_site/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php:128
```

How to disable the oauth log?

Comment: **The user credentials were incorrect**

Comment: Do you want to hide the error from being logged, or to fix the problem which causes the error?

Comment: just add a new user

Comment: I want to hide the error so that it does not get into the laravel.log file when the wrong password etc. The login is working if I give you valid email/password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add that exception to the `$dontReport` array in `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`.

```
protected $dontReport = [
    \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
    // ....
    \League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::class,
];
```

This should disable the reporting (logging) of that exception. For more info, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#the-exception-handler